# Not able to see xquery result in qconsole while CRUD operation is going on using MarkLogic Java API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have a scenario in which we are doing multiple CRUD operations on available documents in specific collection and simultaneously we are pulling data from that specific collection to show it on UI.

For Example - lets assume I have a collection called **Inventory** and I am updating(Doing CRUD Operation) on multiple documents available in **Inventory** collection using JAVA api and simultaneously I am pulling data from **Inventory** collection using XQuery to show it on UI but when JAVA api is performing CRUD operation at that time I am not able to get the xquery result.

Comment: Related to the answer below, https://www.marklogic.com/blog/how-marklogic-supports-acid-transactions/  Depending on your consistency requirements, you can change the MVCC setting for the app server from contemporaneous to non-blocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query will not show those changes until the update commits. That's by design. If you're saying that you have updates that have been committed and you're not seeing those, perhaps it's because your query started before the updated committed.

Relevant reference: [Understanding Transactions in MarkLogic Server](https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/guide/app-dev/transactions#chapter)